# JS/JQuery: наложить одну картинку на другую

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery

Есть слайдер:

```
<div class="slick-track" style="opacity: 1; width: 3292px;">
    <div class="main-slider__slide slick-slide slick-current slick-active" data-slick-index="0" aria-hidden="false" style="width: 1646px; position: relative; left: 0px; top: 0px; z-index: 999; opacity: 1;" tabindex="0">
        <img src="/aa.png" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="main-slider__slide slick-slide" data-slick-index="1" aria-hidden="true" style="width: 1646px; position: relative; left: -1646px; top: 0px; z-index: 998; opacity: 0;" tabindex="-1">
        <img src="/ab.png" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

css:

```
.slick-list {
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.slick-initialized .slick-slide {
    display: block;
}
img {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Необходимо, с помощью JS или JQuery (НЕ CSS) наложить поверх изображений aa и ab, небольшое изображение B со ссылкой `<a href="">`

Примерно так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

На CSS всё понятно, но так как слайдер, и решение временное, надо быстро это отключить. Поэтому нужно решение на JS/JQuery.

Comment: Позиция элемента задается через CSS. Без него вам не обойтись.

Comment: Нужно для начала видеть слайдер в действие, ну а так, просто **нужно добавить dom элемент средствами JS** после загрузки страницы или инициализации скрипта слайдера **и указать ему позиционирование с помощью css**